# ABAC return serialized permissions

Tags: security, permissions, abac

How can we get possible actions (permissions) with ABAC? I need to say to front-end that this button should be hidden, as this action is restricted for for this particular case, and for another not.

Currently only hybrid RBAC/ABAC model is what I'm thinking about, but it is still not covering all the cases, as we might have unauthenticated access, permissions for which will not be covered with RBAC, therefore that should be covered with ABAC.

The question is it possible with ABAC to collect all allowed actions for this user for the current object?

Comment: Hi, can you please clarify your question? Are you trying to restrict UI elements based on attributes?

Comment: @MichaelCGood, Yes I do. I updated the question.

Comment: I encounter this problem as well, with also using nodejs as backend language. Now my solution is only sending frontend all permissions of current user and let frontend do condition rendering by judging the permissions. I wonder what you have done about this question at last, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can restrict UI elements based on the user's attributes. And if a user's attributes change, like the user is promoted or demoted, then the front end will be adjusted based on your policy once the logic is implemented.

I have an example project on Github that demonstrates restricting a UI element with ABAC using Java + Spring Security: https://github.com/michaelcgood/spring-security-ui-demo

As I mentioned, I work for Axiomatics and this project is configured to work with an Axiomatics project in the `pdp.properties`. However, this project could be used with other software implementing XACML for ABAC with the proper properties settings.

If you don't use Java, then the project won't be as useful to you. However, it certainly does demonstrate what you are asking - that UI elements can be restricted.

The front end framework used is Thymeleaf, a server side Java template engine that is HTML friendly.

And the code that restricts a UI element by applying a resource ID is this:

`<div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: green" sec:authorize="XACMLDecisionUI('secretmessage')">
                    <p style="color:white" align="center">Message only available to senior admins (seniority == 2).</p>
</div>`

If you do happen to be using Axiomatics software, please let me know in the comments and I have further guidance I could give you.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using Node.js, TypeScript and there are nothing that really solves ABAC tasks really well. So, I'm implementing sort of my solution, that I believe after sometime will be rewritten to accept XACML as well.

Comment: Hi, whether you use Node.js or some other technology, it is really just a matter of passing the attributes and enforcing it on the PEP side. If you'd like you can start another question and show how are you passing the attributes, you can ping me and I can take a look. Also some XACML implementations support REST. If I've answered your question, feel free to accept my answer :-)

Comment: We are using client side rendering, and can't do additional requests for each UI element that should be hidden. We are having permissions request route that returning all permissions for current context for user. So for now, I see that we can only simulate this.

Comment: I see. It shouldn't need to be additional requests for each UI element. I think on load you could send the attributes in JSON format.

Comment: And that's the point. Effectively collect those attributes, because, as far as I understand their number is unlimited and defined by PIP.

Comment: Do you have any code your can share that shows how you are currently trying to do this?

Comment: Just initial one, but it is irrelevant in terms of this discussion. It's more a lack of teory than practice. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

[ABAC](https://www.nist.gov/publications/guide-attribute-based-access-control-abac-definition-and-considerations) is a broad concept that does not specify this kind of low-level behavior; and it is difficult to give a universal best practice for all ABAC frameworks, since there is a growing bunch of them possibly quite different: some of them are standard (eg. [OASIS XACML](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-en.html), [NIST NGAC](https://www.nist.gov/publications/exploring-next-generation-access-control-methodologies)), others non-standard yet generic (eg. [OPA](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/)), others product-specific (eg. [Kubernetes ABAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/abac/)).

Anyway, in XACML - the most mature standard - you use the [Multiple Decision Profile](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-multiple-v1-spec-en.html) (e.g. scheme 3.3 *Repeated attribute categories*) which allows to request multiple authorization decisions in a single XACML Request:

```
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
   <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
      <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
         <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">/objects/XXX</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
   </Attributes>
   <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
      <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="false">
         <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">bob</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
   </Attributes>
   <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
      <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="true">
         <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">create</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
   </Attributes>
   <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
      <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="true">
         <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
   </Attributes>
   <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
      <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="true">
         <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">update</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
   </Attributes>
   <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
      <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="true">
         <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">delete</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
   </Attributes>
</Request>
```

In this example, we are requesting authorizations for a given user (bob) and resource (/objects/XXX) but multiple actions at once (create, read, update, delete). A compliant PDP returns a single XACML Response with multiple Results, one per individual authorization decision request. The *IncludeInResult* tells which attributes to include in the response so that the PEP can correlate.

Open source XACML implementations such as [AuthzForce](https://github.com/authzforce/core) and AT&T XACML support this Multiple Decision Profile.